# Launching another app in the background iOS

Tags: ios, background-process

I am certain I already know the answer to this question, but I figured it was worth an ask.

I am working on an app that uses another app's custom URL Scheme to launch it, and then send the user to a specific page in the other app.  I use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:URLScheme];
```

However, due to a bug in the other app (that I have no control over), if the app isn't running in the background, the URL will launch the app, and keep it on the home page rather than sending the user to the correct page within the app.  If the app is running in the background, the process works as expected.  I find this to be an unfortunate user experience that sometimes a link lands them on the home page and sometimes it lands them on the correct page.

I am using a way to detect if the app is running in the background or not which is working successfully.  The question here is if the app is not running in the background can I make it launch without sending the user there until it launches.  Or said differently send the user there (which puts my app into background) and once a user lands on the app, then send the request again to send them to the right page?

Again, I am sure I already know the answer to this, but thought I would see what you all thought.